# No suitable default RequestUpgradeStrategy found in a new generated jhipster application

Tags: spring, jhipster, spring-websocket, jhipster-gateway

I'm working on Jhipster micro-services project, all works fine and good until i a

```
 websocket spring-websocket
```

into the gateway application in my JDL file, now when I run the project I always get a failure

```
 Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'stompWebSocketHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable default RequestUpgradeStrategy found
```

the application I'am use is right of the box generated from jhipster generator 7.0.0

the JDL I use is :

```
application {

config {

baseName usergateway,

packageName fr.teamsyst.trade4talent.usergateway,

applicationType gateway,

authenticationType jwt,

databaseType mongodb,

devDatabaseType mongodb,

prodDatabaseType mongodb,

serviceDiscoveryType eureka,

testFrameworks [protractor],

nativeLanguage fr,

languages [fr, en],

jhiPrefix t4t,

websocket spring-websocket,

}

entities *

}
```

Comment: There is a new issue reported at https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/14567

Answer (score 0):

Add spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency to pom.xml

Add spring.main.web-application-type: reactive to application.yml